# How do I add then select the dynamic control I just added

Tags: vb.net

I've got an application in VB.net which adds a picturebox to the selected mouse position within another picturebox control.  I need to create a click event to select that new picturebox so I can drag it and drop it to a new location in the event that the first one was wrong or use a keypress event, those events I will code later, but I can not figure out how to select ANY of the dynamic controls.

In vb6 there was a way to select an index of the control, but there is no such animal in VB.net.

I've tried control groups, but for some reason I'm not getting results from them.

Here is the code I have so far

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As System.Object, 
          e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click

    Dim pb As New PictureBox
    pb.BackColor = Color.Blue
    Me.PictureBox1.Controls.Add(pb)
    pb.Size = New Size(64, 110)
    pb.Location = New Point(Cursor.Position.X - 64, Cursor.Position.Y - 110)
    pb.Visible = True

End Sub
```

What in the name of all good things am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like you are referring to the VB6 control arrays.   If you give your new picture box a Name, you can refer to it via `Controls(picBoxName)`; if you are creating multiples, use a List to store the name(s) (`List(Of String)`) or control reference (`List(of PictureBox)`).  You will also want to look up `AddHandler` if you want the new controls to respond to events.

Comment: Some controls in `.net` are designed to *not* host child controls. This includes controls like `PictureBox`, `TextBox`, `Button` etc. Add the new PB to the forms control collection instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a generic event handler before time, using the `sender` parameter to refer to the object that raised the event.

```
Private Sub PictureBoxes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim pb = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)

    'Use pb here.
End Sub
```

When you create your control at run time, use an `AddHandler` statement to attach the method to the event.

```
Dim pb As New PictureBox

AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf PictureBoxes_Click
```

That said, if you want to implement drag-n-drop then it's not the Click event you should be handling.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, the drag-drop feature is later, right now I am just trying to address the dynamic control just created and this is all a good start.

Comment: By the way, whenever you use `AddHandler`, you should write a corresponding `RemoveHandler` statement to detach the method from the event when you're done with the object.

Comment: You see, that is in part an element of the problem.  I tried the code posted above and it indeed selected the object which I wanted to select, but then it locked out further attempts at adding a new object.  There was some method which I managed to get a partial effect from your code to work, but it is not one which I can say resolved yet on this topic.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what actually happened?  "it locked out further attempts at adding a new object" doesn't really mean too much.

Comment: Plutonix, how would I use the dynamic name in an event and which event would I use to trigger it for selection?

Comment: Sure, I clicked on the picturebox which was the target for the primary event handler, this added a new instance of PB.  The object appeared on screen and was selectable; however, when I elected to manipulate the primary picturebox to add another dynamic control, it would not allow me to do so;  As well, I had a specific pen event for the primary picturebox which would paint to PB if I triggered the event after the dynamic creation.

Answer (score 0):

This little bit of code took some time, but I was able to do what I set out to so far...


**This is before the Sub Main event**

```
   Public Class dynamicPB                                     'create a picturebox element which 
                                                              'can be called anytime
        Inherits PictureBox                                   'sets the type of control to a 
                                                              'picturebox

    Public Sub New()                                       'sets the function of the new box to 
                                                           'default values
        MyBase.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
        MyBase.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        MyBase.Height = 50
        MyBase.Width = 26
    End Sub
End Class
```

**in the actual main class**

```
Private Sub <control_event> (blah...) Blah...
    Dim intPosAdj_X As Integer = 13                         'get an offset for the cursor 
    Dim intPosAdj_Y As Integer = 25

        Dim newPictureBox As New dynamicPB                  'sets the click of the mouse into a           
                                                            'mode of drawing a new PB
        With newPictureBox                                      'clean use of the code
        AddHandler newPictureBox.Click, _
            AddressOf PictureBox_Click                      'establishes events for the mouse 
                                                            'activity on the objects
        AddHandler newPictureBox.MouseEnter, _
            AddressOf PictureBox_MouseEnter
        AddHandler newPictureBox.MouseLeave, _
            AddressOf PictureBox_MouseLeave
        pbName += 1                                         'gives a unique name to the 
                                                            'picturebox in an "array" style
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point _
                (xPos - intPosAdj_X, yPos - intPosAdj_Y)        'establish where the box goes 
                                                                'and center the object on the 
                                                                'mouse pointer

            .Visible = True                                     'ensures that the box is visible
            .Name = pbName                                      'names the new control
        End With
        Controls.Add(newPictureBox)                             'add control to form

    End Sub
Private Sub PictureBox_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
     Dim dblMouseClick As Double = CType(DirectCast _
         (e, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs).Button, MouseButtons) _
                                                                'make it simple to manipulate        
                                                                'the event by putting the long 
                                                                'code into a variable
        If dblMouseClick = MouseButtons.Left Then
            MsgBox("Left CLick")
        ElseIf dblMouseClick = MouseButtons.Right Then
            MsgBox("right click")
        Else
            MsgBox("Center")
        End If
```

This actually resolves the issue of adding and being able to select the object 
Thanks for all of the suggestions and help